# I wrote a request xsl that transforms an xml request to another one but it doesn't work as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

The Request in xml is :

```
 <NS2:BookTicket xmlns:NS2="http://station.com.ph/schemas/bookTicket">
      <NS2:transaction_header>
        <NS3:Ticket_id xmlns:NS3="http://station.com.ph/schemas/common-types">
        1993</NS3:Ticket_id>
        <NS4:request_datetime xmlns:NS4="http://station.com.ph/schemas/common-types">
        2014-11-04T15:26:27</NS4:request_datetime>
        <NS5:request_reference_no xmlns:NS5="http://smarthub.com.ph/schemas/common-types">
        141104165416</NS5:request_reference_no>
        <NS6:send_sms xmlns:NS6="http://smarthub.com.ph/schemas/common-types">
        N</NS6:send_sms>
        <NS7:send_sms_language xmlns:NS7="http://smarthub.com.ph/schemas/common-types">
        en</NS7:send_sms_language>
      </NS2:transaction_header>
      <NS2:transaction_body>
 <NS2:idn>00201220202121</NS2:idn>
        <sss>2570778508</sss>
              </NS2:transaction_body>
    </NS2:BookTicket>
```

The output xml that is expected (That I want) is :

```
<Root>
<numberid1>00201220202121</numberid1>
<numberid2>2570778508</numberid2>
</Root>
```

(I want to extract the value inside idn and put it in a new element in the transformed xml request called  also I want to extract the value insides sss and put it in a new element in the transformed xml request called )

I wrote this request xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Root">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="*//BookTicket">
                    <xsl:element name="numberid1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="*//idn" />
                    </xsl:element>
                               <xsl:element name="numberid2">
                        <xsl:value-of select="*//sss" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Actual transformed xml after applying xsl is : 
Why can't it find the BookTicket or create the new elements? is it something related to namespaces?

Comment: The Actual transformed xml after applying xsl is : <Root/>

Comment: I want to extract the value inside idn and put it in a new element in the transformed xml request called numberid1 also I want to extract the value insides sss and put it in a new element in the transformed xml request called numberid2)

Comment: "*is it something related to namespaces?*" Yes. And also your condition: `<xsl:when test="*//BookTicket">` is false, even if one disregards the namespace issue. `BookTicket` is not a descendant of any element.

Comment: <sss>2570778508</sss> is <NS2:sss>2570778508</NS2:sss> with namespace NS2

Comment: Huh? I am afraid you're not making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:NS2="http://station.com.ph/schemas/bookTicket"
exclude-result-prefixes="NS2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="NS2:BookTicket/NS2:transaction_body">
            <numberid1><xsl:value-of select="NS2:idn"/></numberid1>
            <numberid2><xsl:value-of select="sss"/></numberid2>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```